# Magento 2: Blank Spots on Category (Product Listing) Page

Tags: magento2, category-products, grid-layout

Began managing a website on Magento 2.3.3 and on most of the category pages there are blank spots. I know we have Porto and  You can see in the images below. It's not consistent on desktop as sometimes it's 2  products on the left and sometimes it's only 1.

I'm not a developer, but understand the basics of coding. I need to be able to give them something tangible to fix. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: example 1]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sonia, I'm trying to open your store link but it shows "you have been blocked" error. Can you help me to access your store?  https://persianbasket.com